# How to fix w3wp.exe errors after windows 7 and 8.1 updates of August 12th 2015?

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows-update, w3wp, .net-4.6

Some ASP.NET 4.5 websites throw the following error continuously on every request after the latest windows updates (August 12th 2015).

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
>   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18933, time stamp: 0x55a6a16f
>   Exception code: 0xe0434352
>   Fault offset: 0x000000000000b3dd
>   Faulting process id: 0x2bb8
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d0d5ac15c25873
>   Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
>   Report Id: 58cdc89d-419f-11e5-8650-782bcbaf10f4

I confirmed on other PC's that the windows update is to blame, both for windows 7 and 8.1.

To try and fix it, I tried updating nuget packages, switching the .NET framework to 4.5.2, reconfiguring IIS, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to uninstall .NET 4.6 RC and install the regular .NET 4.6.

Answer (score 3):

I had mine fixed by uninstalling Security Update for Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6 RC KB3083186. Microsoft should correct this soon for MVS 2013 and MVS 2015